# GameRotationVector confusion - values are incomplete (cp. RotationVector)

Tags: android, orientation, android-sensors, android-orientation, azimuth

The **GameRotationVector** in Android does not behave as expected from the doc (1). The Android doc says that the **GameRotationVector** should give the same values as the **RotationVector** sensor, with the difference that it does NOT consider the real azimuth (magnetic north). In this case I am talking about the azimuth which I get by the following code.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotMatrix,event.values);
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, rotMatrixRemapped);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotMatrixRemapped, vals);
    myAzimuthInRadiant = vals[0];
}
```

The **RotationVector** sensor gives values from **-pi to pi** when I turned my device in 360° - everything fine, but look at the second picture.

[image: RotationVector values are as expected from -pi to pi]

In the second picture you can see that the **GameRotationVector** gives values from **pi/2 to pi** and vice versa on the negative site. That's, summing up = **pi**, which is half the range of the RotationVector.

So what is wrong here?

[image: GameRotationVector values are just from pi/2 to pi (pos. and neg.)]

(1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR

Comment: I don't know the answer for your question but I have something to add.  When using normal ROTATION_VECTOR, and I let my device idle on a flat surface, the value is near to 0. But when using GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR, the value is SOMETIMES not near to 0. The only solution I found is to restart the device, and the value of GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR will back to normal. However, it will become wrong again after awhile, possibly DRIFT. (but android docs stated GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR will not drift???)